# Stop webpage from shifting when window size is adjusted

Tags: html, css

So I have a webpage, but when I start to shrink the size of the window, all the elements start to stack on top of each other, and it all looks messed up. i.e.

[image: Youtube]

Youtube just cuts everything off, instead of all the images stacking on each other. How can I achieve a similar effect?

Comment: CSS property `min-width` plus an `overflow-x`.

Answer (score 0):

Block elements by default adjust in width to the parent, so if you don't give a fix `width` to the container (or `min-width`) in pixels the width will be `100%` and by resizing the child elements adjust to it. Add a `width`/`min-width` to the container:

```
#wrapper{
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  ...
}
```

Comment: It works for part of the webpage, while the other parts still get messed up when resizing. Maybe it's because I used relative positioning?